# Make iMac remember monitor positions after restart

Tags: macos, imac, display, thunderbolt

**I have an iMac with the following specs:**

[image]

---

**I have 2 20'' hp monitors that are always connected to my Mac. They are connected with 2 DisplayLink USB to VGA adapters. I keep the monitors positioned as follows:**

[image]

---

**Unfortunately, everytime I restart my Mac, the screen positions revert to the default settings of:**

[image]

---

This is very frustrating.

**How can I make my Mac remember and reapply my monitor positions when I restart?**

FYI, I also have 2 Thunderbolt to DVI adapters that I can use but it results in the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing would be if the preference for your user that stores the setting is corrupt.

To test this, turn off auto login, make a new user, log in to that user  and arrange the monitors as you like. Log out of the test user, restart the Mac and log into the test user. This will let you know if the system problem or if it's a user problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot tonight. Unfortunately, I just updated to El Capitan which apparently hates external monitors (despite Apple's insistence that it provides enhanced monitor support). Now the Windows Server randomly crashes killing both external monitors and requires a reboot just to get them to come back on which is super fun and appears to be a very common problem.

Comment: I hadn't noticed before because of all the issues with El Capitan, but with the update, my system does now remember and reapply my settings when I restart. So, the issue I asked about seems to be resolved by the update (directly or indirectly)........now if they can just fix all the other issues it introduced, I might be able to actually use my monitors again. Thanks for the input though +1